# Regex for all non-current sites

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression such that every link that is not to `www.example.com` links in a new window. I think this would give me everything that **does** link to it. How would I get everything that does not?

```
(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.(com|net|gov|org)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!(http:\/\/)?(www\.)example\.(com|net|gov|org))(http:\/\/)?(www\.).*\.(com|net|gov|org)`

http://regexr.com?30nfp

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, what does the `(?!` do at the beginning?

Comment: `(?!)` is a negative lookahead assertion.  It basically means NOT.  If the string matches the pattern after the `?!` then it will exclude it from the match.

Comment: This won't work for non http links (https) or for subdomains or links that don't contain www.

Comment: I'm not sure those are the requirements the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

to your page, then use the regex you've got to add `target="_self"` to matching links?

Comment: I need everything that is not example.com though. How would I add the `not` ?